# possible problems of an sms gateway?

Tags: linux, sms, bulksms

What could be the possible problems of an sms gateway?
If you are trying to create a system having large volume of transactions? 
Is data loss rampant? are there any issues about SMS gateway? or there a huge issue about the problems?

Answer (score 2):

I also notice this post is old but hope this helps.

As you haven't mentioned how you are sending the messages i.e. VIA GSM sim, or through a aggregator. I am guessing you are talking about database storage?

The way we do it is store all the messages in a mysql table tbl_sms_queue for instance, this is assigned to an campaign and also has a status frag ENUM(pending or sent).

table sample:

```
tbl_sms_queue
- pk_message_id INT PK AI
- fk_user_id INT
- fk_campaign_id INT
- fk_sender_name INT
...
- status ENUM('0','1') DEF 0
```

Then our gearman servers parse through the db, we can sent approx 4500 - 5000 messages per minute.

FYI: I am an architect of an bulk sms platform and our database backend is a custom installation of clustered mysql and a gearman implication.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "data loss" is a concern. I think the problem you can encounter is that the sender/receiver can only work with 1 message at once.

Sending/receiving a SMS take X seconds, and if you indeed send/receive a lot of these short messages, your queue will grow rapidly and you will soon need to be able to send/receive multiple SMS at once, using more phone lines.